# Eclipse and German umlauts in String resources

Tags: android, character-encoding, localization, embedded-resource, android-resources

This may be a completely n00b question, but does Eclipse offer a way for me to use German umlauts in String resource files (res/values/strings.xml) without having to use their UTF-8 codes? Like to define a different charset for the XML file or whatever, being able to type in 'native' German language?

The reason why I'm asking is that writing and proof-reading a larger strings with UTF-8 codes in every 2nd word file causes extreme headaches and is prone for typos.

Comment: AFAICT, you just type in the umlaut: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/res/res/values-de/strings.xml

Comment: Your XML file should itself be UTF-8; hence the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the top.  If Eclipse doesn't allow you to edit and save it with a literal umlaut character in it, then I would think that's an Eclipse problem, and nothing to do with Android per se.

Comment: hmm... I can enter the umlauts in the strings.xml file -- but in the app (at least for now, the emulator), I only see gibberish instead of the umlauts.

Comment: It seems like you made these files using Windows NotePad... Make sure the files themselves are saved as UTF-8 (The xml heading may not suffice) and not Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1. Use a decent text editor and save the files AS ... and choose the UTF-8 encoding

Comment: I am using Eclipse! If I look at the source files with a binary editor, they seem to be saved in UTF-8 format. However, on a closer look, I think I may mess up encoding with this way I load these strings: webView1.loadData(URLEncoder.encode("<string name=\"hello\"><html><body>" + getString(R.string.strIntro1) + "</body></html></string>","utf-8").replaceAll("\\+"," "), "text/html", "utf-8");